# Making an EditText object accept only numeric values

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-method

I'd like to create programatically an EditText within this attribute:

```
android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"
```

In brief I'd like it to accept only numeric values. How do I have to set my EditText object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding method for inputType is

[public void setInputType (int type)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29)

So something like the below should work (untested)

```
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL )
```