# Android application crashes, Button or Conditional won't work?

Tags: java, android

Im pretty much a newbie at this so i could use some help to know why does my app keep crashing ? I've tried a lot of ways and this is the best I've come so far.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView lastAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    final TextView answerLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final TextView answerLabel1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final TextView answerLabel2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    final EditText enteredNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button getAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    getAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

            @Override   
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                  //rand gene
                     int randomNumber2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(99);
                      int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(99);

            String number = "";
            String number2 = "";
            String jtext = " Times ";
            number2= Integer.toString(randomNumber2);
            number= Integer.toString(randomNumber);
            answerLabel.setText(jtext);
            answerLabel1.setText(number2);
            answerLabel2.setText(number);

            String content = enteredNumber.getText().toString();
```

> When i comment the conditional the app works fine, but thats not all that i want
>   I suppose the problem is in the conditional but i can't seem to find it.
>   no errors what so ever on eclipse.

```
            if (content != null){
                int anInt=Integer.parseInt(content);
                int result= randomNumber2 *randomNumber;

                    if(anInt == result ){

                      Context context =getApplicationContext();
                            CharSequence text = "That's correct!!";
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                            toast.show();

                    } else{ 

                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "That's not correct";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show(); 
                    }
                    lastAnswer.setText(content);
            }

            }
        });}
```

So what im trying to do here (mind the noob code) is just generate 2 random numbers, display them and then have the user input the result, compare it, notify if right or not and then regenerate.. I've been working on this for days

any help is appreciated, even new ways of following this code. thanks.

Comment: Please add a stack trace and a note to show which line is crashing.

Comment: crash => stacktrace or close the question

Comment: are you asking the user to guess the result of 2 random numbers that you are going to choose after he inputed the answer ? that's doesn't seem quite right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably surround your parsing with a try/catch. Users input being parsed back into a number might not always work - especially with EditTexts. Change

```
int anInt=Integer.parseInt(content);
```

So it is

```
  int anInt= -1;
  try{
   anInt = Integer.parseInt(content);
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException e)
  {
    //Show toast or dialog
  }
```

Also to make life easier, you should make the EditText [accept in only numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330519/making-an-edittext-object-accept-only-numeric-values).

Comment: This is also a good idea, in general.

Comment: Im trying this, could you be a bit more specific though?

Comment: @user1990939 Which part? You set the int to a default value (eg -1), then you try to parse, and if it fails the catch block is executed, which can contain anything you want it to. Of course if the parsing failed, you might want to stop execution (via a boolean or return statement).

Comment: that's very specific already. What is it you don't understand with "surround your potential exceptions with try catch blocks" ?

Comment: NEVERMIND that, its working like a charm, THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCHH  you have no idea how much you've helped!

Comment: @user1990939 make the variables global.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm .... Why are you using the application context to show the toasts? I recall seeing a recent question with the same issue. Try using the activity context (`MainActivity.this`) instead.

Answer (score -1):

clean your project after you add the comment, the run it again

will edit answer if this isn't a solution for you